# How do I apply changes to a template file?

Tags: html, dwt

I've uploaded the new file via FTP, but the changes didn't take effect: http://intrepidtraveler.com/Templates/press.dwt

Why is this the case? http://intrepidtraveler.com/media/ (Trying to update the image links on the left hand side).

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver templates aren't integrated after upload.  Rather, Dreamweaver keeps track of which pages utilize which templates, and when you save a copy of the template should prompt you to update all pages that rely on the template.  Then you must upload each dependent page.

Comment: It never prompted me when I saved to the server. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: The synchronization information isn't stored by the server, so it has no idea which pages are linked to the template.  If you uploaded the template before saving it, it's possible that it never gave you the chance to update the children files.  Try making a meaningless change to the template (add a space, then delete it) and just save the template locally.  If the children files are properly recognized by Dreamweaver, it should prompt you to propagate the changes to all children files.

Comment: "Putting dependent files on press.dwt" But the new changes didn't take effect.

Comment: Dependent files are a different feature altogether.  There should be an option when you save changes to the template to update all files using that template.